# Python: I have right result but in wrong format. Practicing with strings. Any idea how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Code:

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = str(users).split()
  return group + ":" + str(members)

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"]))
print(group_list("Users", ""))
```

Actual output:

```
Marketing:["['Mike',", "'Karen',", "'Jake',", "'Tasha']"]
Engineering:["['Kim',", "'Jay',", "'Tom']"]
Users:[]
```

How can I achieve the following desired output instead?

```
Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha
Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom
Users:
```

Comment: Show the real and expected output as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: real output goes after " Output is",  expected after # in a print line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you are probably looking for:

```
def group_list(group, users):
  users_string = ", ".join(users)
  return "{}: {}".format(group, users_string)

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"]))
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"]))
print(group_list("Users", ""))
```

You can join items of arrays easily using `join`. I prefer building strings using str.format instead of concatenate them using the "+" operator.

str.format: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings
str.join: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this. I will give a short summary of what this does.

```
def group_list(group, users):
  return group + ": " + ', '.join(users)

print(group_list("Marketing", ["Mike", "Karen", "Jake", "Tasha"])) 
print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"]))
print(group_list("Users", ""))
```

Displays:

```
Marketing: Mike, Karen, Jake, Tasha
Engineering: Kim, Jay, Tom
Users:
```

Explanation:

```
', '.join(users)
```

Is used to join a series of strings from the list `users` with a spacer, in this case a comma followed by a space.

Why did your code not work?

```
members = str(users).split()
    return group + ":" + str(members)
```

`str(users)` returns the `str` representation of a `list` which means it literally returns a string that looks similar to the following (notice that the string has literal quotes embedded within the string and has square brackets embedded, as well:

```
"['Mike', 'Karen', 'Jake', 'Tasha']"
```

When you call `.split()` on this result, the default behavior of `.split()` is to split on whitespace and then return a `list`. Which means we get back something that looks like this:

```
["['Mike',",    "'Karen',",     "'Jake',",     "'Tasha']"]
```

We see that this is a `list` and is surrounded by square brackets and that the `list` contains a bunch of short `str` objects:

```
"['Mike',"
"'Karen',"
"'Jake',"
"'Tasha']"
```

The next thing that happens in your code is that we try to convert the members `list` into a `str` by using `str(members)` to get the string representation of the members `list`.

Comment: Saying "We require..." hiding behind the rules and community, being afraid to take responsibility.

Comment: Thank you for proving my point by deleting like 6-7 previous comments :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `group_list` function you've written, `users` is a list, so running `str(users)` converts the standard list format (with brackets) into a string, which is then separated by spaces with `.split()` (which is meant to split a string into a list). What you want to do is use the `.join()` method to join all the elements in your input list into a single string

Try this:

```
    def group_list(group, users):
        # Join each element of users, separated by ', '
        output = group + ': ' + ', '.join(users)
        return output
```